# My JavaScript "click" function only works once

Tags: javascript, function, event-listener

I'm trying to give some style to my cursor with Javascript, with a mark that follows the cursor everywhere on screen. Now I'm trying to apply a specific style when I click on the page. The problem is that my function works but only once. Then I have to refresh the page so it can work again. I've used an addEventListener method with 'click', that I think is the proper method.

```js
var cursor1 = document.querySelector(".cursor1");
var cursor2 = document.querySelector(".cursor2");
/*

this was some test.

function testscale(){
    cursor1.animate(
        [{transform: 'scale(1)'},{transform: 'scale(0)'}],
        {duration:200}
        );
*/


document.addEventListener('click', function(){
    cursor1.classList.add("cursoranimation");
});
--//


document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e){
    cursor1.style.cssText = cursor2.style.cssText = "left: " + e.clientX + "px; top: " + e.clientY + "px;";
});
//-les styles sont dans ../Pages/Scss/Base/_undefined
```

```css
.cursoranimation{
    transform: scale(1);
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    animation: cursoranimation2 1000ms backwards;
}

.cursor1{
    position:fixed;
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border:1px solid black;
    border-radius:50%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
}

.cursor2{
    position:fixed;
    width: 8px;
    height: 8px;
    background-color:#c6c6c6;
    border-radius:50%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    pointer-events:none;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 1;
}

@keyframes cursoranimation2 {
    0% {
        background-color: white;
        transform: scale(1);
        transform:translate(-15%,-15%);
    }
    50% {
        background-color: rgb(179, 247, 202);
        transform:scale(0.6);
        transform:translate(-25%,-25%);
    }
    75% {
        background-color: rgb(179, 247, 202);
        transform:scale(0.4);
        transform:translate(-35%,-35%);
    }
    100% {
        background-color: rgb(132, 247, 176);
        transform:scale(0.3);
        transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
    }
}
```

Do you have some advice for my situation ? Thank you ! (i'm not using jquery)

Comment: Please add some HTML so your snippet demo works properly.

Comment: The click listener is adding a class. Unless something else removes the class, the second click won't have any effect.

Comment: Ok Barmar you helped so much. I need something to remove the class after a certain amount of time. You rock so much thank you, I was tired !